# Data from fetch URL and using that data in another function (Question about Scope)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, scope, fetch

I have one function using fetch to get the URL, response and data.
And another function that does something with it.

```js
async function getData(){
  const response = await fetch("URL");
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

// My JSON file is an Object with a key:value pairing.
// "Array": [array of stuff]
// I want to get one of the values from the [array of stuff].

// Since getData() returns data as Promise, I have to use .then() to access it, right?
// This example below console logs the first index of the array within my JSON Object.
// That works fine, but when I try to use "return", it doesn't do anything.
// It just says "Promise {<pending>}".
getData().then(data=> console.log(data["Array"][0]));

// Obviously I shouldn't be using console.log, but using return doesn't do anything...

// Here I will use the data from the above getData() function in another function below.
function doSomething(){
  // Do something with data["Array"][0]
}
```

What if I want to use the value from my .then() in another function? How do I go about doing that?
I guess what I'm trying to say is how do I use data from my async function in another separate function?
The scope is confusing me...

Comment: If you don't want to `console.log` it, just `doSomething(data.Array[0])` with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as an argument to that another function.

In your example

```js
async function getData(){
  const response = await fetch("URL");
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

function doSomething(data) {
  // here you do something with data
  console.log(data)
}

getData().then(doSomething)
```

Async function returns a Promise.
Promise can be in one of three states - pending, resolved or rejected.

`Promise.then()` takes two arguments - callbacks - functions. Those functions will be called when promise is resolved or rejected. The first one is called upon resolve. Promise passess the result as an argument to that function.

In the above example you pass `doSomething` as a function to be called back when `getData()` resolves.

You can read more about Promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

And also about async/await [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)